# Camel get response from Route

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am able to called Web Service, now what ever response came from web service, i need to fetch same response in java code so that i am able to further processing.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="false">
<route id="my_Sample_Camel_Route_with_CXF">
    <from uri="file:src/data?noop=true"/>
    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="&gt;&gt;&gt; ${body}"/>
    <to uri="cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdlURL=src/main/resources/META-INF/stockquote.wsdl&amp;serviceName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}StockQuote&amp;portName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}StockQuoteSoap&amp;dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="&gt;&gt;&gt; ${body}"/>
</route>
```

Instead of logging using

Comment: You need to unmarshal the response into a Java object?

Comment: but how i get raw string in above case its a xml response from camel to java class.

Comment: Assuming you have generated `jaxb` classes from the `wsdl`, you can add a 'marshal` step to convert to an object. See http://camel.apache.org/jaxb.html for details.